# expressing k elements of N sized set using intersections of subsets

Tags: combinatorics

Some time ago I came across a interesting puzzle: Lets say we have set of N elements and we need to construct such subsets, that we could uniquely express any randomly chosen K elements from set N using their intersections. What is the minimum amount of such subsets required if K is known?

So far, I have managed to find such subsets for K=1 (inspired by binary search) and got some unproved ideas for K=2.

I am looking for some tips how could I proceed here. Thank you!

Comment: Can you show your work for $K=1$?